# XMLHttpRequest responsetext не принимает новые значения

Tags: javascript

Отправляю 1-й запрос на сервер, получаю ответ. Отправляю 2-й, ответ от сервера уже другой, посмотрел через Charles, но выводится ответ из 1-го запроса, что делать? (Проблема возникает в Chrome)

```
var response31 = new XMLHttpRequest();

response31.onload = function() {
    alert(this.responseText);
    var response3 = new XMLHttpRequest();

    response3.onload = function() {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }
    response3.onerror = function() {
        stopper();
    }

    response3.open('POST', protocol + '....', true);
    response3.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    response3.send('....');
}

response31.onerror = function() {
    stopper();
}

response31.open('POST', protocol + '....', true);
response31.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
response31.send('.....');
```

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что ответ 1го запроса выводится два раза? Или что выводится только ответ 1го и не выводится 2го несмотря на то что оба пришли?

Comment: @MakarovAV И тот, и тот запросы проходят, но и там и там выводится ответ 1-го запроса.  Хотя, если ответы отловить, то они разные

Comment: так стоп, Вы последовательно с ними работаете или один в обработчике другого? А то код меняется, непонятно)

Comment: @MakarovAV Один в обработчике другого

Comment: попробуйте обратиться в response3.onload не через this а через response3.responseText

Comment: @MakarovAV До этого так обращался, выходила такая же хрень

Comment: Сдаюсь, методом пристального вглядывания я ошибки не вижу. Придется подождать кого-то более умного или пока я высплюсь. Насколько я понмаю "проблема в Chrome" не значит, что проблема _только_ в chrome, а просто Вы в нем смотрите?
Брейкпоинты в двух обработчиках срабатывают или в одном только?

Comment: @MakarovAV Этот код просто находится в расширении chrome. 
Да дополню немного, 1-вый и 2-рой запрос производятся на одну и ту же страницу (Но ответы разные).